# What is the status of Jessica Jones' daughter in comics?

Tags: comics, marvel, jessica-jones

In comics Jessica Jones and Luke Cage have a daughter, Danielle Cage. But I never got to know what happened to her again, not in the main universe.

So what’s the current status of her daughter in the main Marvel universe? What age she is at, and what has she been doing all this time?

Comment: She's still an infant doing... infant things.

Comment: @phantom42 didn't other people grown compare to her? Or she never got mentioned?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how old she is, but I do know who her nanny is. Doreen Green, AKA Squirrel Girl :-)

Comment: It's comics. People never age unless the plot requires it.

Comment: http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Danielle_Cage_(Earth-616)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can offer you little more than what my esteemed colleagues have already put in the comments.

> **Danielle was born to Luke Cage and Jessica Jones.**
>
> As the Secret Invasion was bound to fail, the Skrull posing as Edwin Jarvis escaped Avengers Tower with Danielle. **However, he did not hurt her and eventually had to return her to her parents**.
>
> During the Heroic Age, **Jessica hired Squirrel Girl as her nanny**. - [Danielle Cage (Earth-616)](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Danielle_Cage_(Earth-616))

[image]

A few relevant stats:

She is unmarried and appears to have no education. Possibly on account of being less than 1 year old.

She has made a total of 90 appearances in comics for Earth-616.